# Flex Sub-Apps and MarhsallingSupport missing in 3.x SDK's

Tags: apache-flex

I'm looking at using Sub-Applications within flex, to enable mutli-versioned compilation.

Specifically, I'm looking to have a Flex 4.x host app that loads Flex 3.6 sub-apps.

The docs state this is possible (and the purpose of sub-apps).  However they specify this:

> When compiling each of these types of applications, you should include
>   the MarshallingSupport class into the main application and
>   sub-applications. You do this with the includes compiler argument, as
>   the following example shows:
>
> `-includes=mx.managers.systemClasses.MarshallingSupport`

However, from what I can tell, `MarhsallingSupport` wasn't included until the 4.x releases.

Looking at the `mx.managers.systemClasses` package for 3.5.0.12683 and 3.4.1.10084 shows no reference of `MarshallingSupport` ([see svn here](http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/tags/3.5.0.12683/frameworks/projects/framework/src/mx/managers/systemClasses/) and [here](http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/tags/3.4.1.10084/frameworks/projects/framework/src/mx/managers/systemClasses/))

This is also true for 3.6a (download of SDK available, but can't find the source).

Am I missing something?  How am I supposed to include this class in the 3.x sub-apps, when it's not available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see http://help.adobe.com/en_US/enterpriseplatform/10.0/AEPDeveloperGuide/WS8cbf8723eeed7311-4cca458e1328d74a115-7fff.html

> Like module bundles, there are no special compilation requirements. You can build the 
>   application bundle SWF in any way that is convenient. Note, however,
>   that application bundles must include marshalling support.
>
> **This is automatic with Flex 3**, but with Flex 4 you must force the inclusion
>   of the MarshallingSupport class in your SWF.
>
> For Flex 4 this can be
>   done by referencing the MarshallingSupport class in your application
>   code (as in the previous example). You can also explicitly force
>   inclusion of the MarshallingSupport class on the mxmlc command line
>   using the following option:
>
> ```
> -includes+=mx.managers.systemClasses.MarshallingSupport
> ```